# How do I make a C program that does not exit immediately when entered an error?

Tags: c

Consider:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<windows.h>

int main() {
    double Height = 0;
    double Diameter = 0;
    double Radius;
    double pi = 3.14;
    double Area;
    double volume;
    printf("Enter the Height in cm: \n");
    scanf("%lf", &Height);
    printf("Enter the Diameter in cm: \n");
    scanf("%lf", &Diameter);
    Radius = Diameter / 2.0;
    Area = pi * Radius * Radius;
    volume = Area * Height;
    printf("\n\n%fcm3\n\n", volume);
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

This is a volume calculator program. Is there a possible way to make my program not exit immediately when I enter an invalid value?

Example: entering a string. If I did that, my program immediately exits.

Comment: Please check the return value from `scanf`, which is well [documented](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/scanf-scanf-l-wscanf-wscanf-l?view=msvc-170). You will find it easier to input with `fgets()` and `sscanf()` and then loop round for another input if there is an error.

Comment: `scanf` is notoriously difficult (if not impossible) to use for user friendly user input. I suggest you don't care about this for the moment an focus on learning the basics of the C language.

Comment: The program doesn't quite "immediately exit". The invalid entry for the first value remains in the input buffer, and is again refused for the second value. The program then outputs the volume `0.000000cm3`.

Answer (score 0):

The [scanf(3)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/scanf.3.html) function is documented to return some integer, which should be tested, and could be `EOF`  (usually some negative integer) or (in your case) 0 on failure. Read also some C standard like [n1570](https://www.iso-9899.info/n1570.html) or better.

You may improve your program to contain a loop, asking for valid input till end of file is given. Try something like:

```
int s = -1;
do {
  printf("Enter the Height in cm: \n");
  s= scanf("%lf", &Height);
  if (s==EOF)
     exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
  else if (s==0)
     printf("invalid number; retrying...\n");
}while (s==0);
```

On Linux, the end-of-file condition is entered with <kbd>Ctrl D</kbd>. See [termios(3)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/termios.3.html) and the [Tty demystified](https://www.linusakesson.net/programming/tty/) page. On Windows (which I never used), it might be <kbd>Ctrl Z</kbd>, but you should check your documentation.

Compile your program with [GCC](https://gcc.gnu.org/) invoked [as](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Invoking-GCC.html) `gcc -Wall -Wextra -g` (to get a lot of warnings and debug information) then use the [GDB](https://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/) debugger to understand its behavior.

You could also use parser generators like [Flex](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flex_(lexical_analyser_generator)) combined with [GNU bison](https://www.gnu.org/software/bison/), or [ANTLR](https://www.antlr.org/). You should also read some chapters of the [Dragon book](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compilers:_Principles,_Techniques,_and_Tools). You might consider reading an entire line with [fgets(3)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fscanf.3.html) (or perhaps [GNU readline](https://tiswww.case.edu/php/chet/readline/rltop.html), if you want the user to be able to *edit* each line) then using [sscanf(3)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/sscanf.3.html) (perhaps with `%n`) on your line buffer or your own parsing routines.

PS. I tend to believe that `#include <windows.h>` is not even needed.

Comment: This answer doesn't address how to get past the invalid input.

Comment: Yes, it suggest testing `scanf`. I won't write the code, the student should write it.

Comment: Testing `scanf` and looping does not in itself solve the problem. It probably won't be `EOF` here but `0`.

Comment: yes i am trying to get the way to get past the invalid input and retry

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch the reason why i  #include<windows.h> is to be able to use the system("pause")

Comment: Are you sure it is needed?  On Linux, `system` is declared in `<stdlib.h>` header (mentioned in the C11 standard) Did you try some `#include <stdlib.h>` instead of `#include <windows.h>` ?